# How can I add a char to a buffer?

Tags: c, char, buffer

```
int appendBuffer(buffer_t buffer, char c)
```

This is the function I have to do. 
And I want to add a `char c` to my variable `buffer`, who is of the type `buffer_t`, beeing `buffer_t` a pointer to `buffer_s`, beeing `buffer_s` the buffer.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? How did (or didn't) it work? What is the *actual* definition of `buffer_t`? What does the structure look like? Please show the actual *code* for the definition of involved types and structures.

Comment: For the purpose of clarity, provide type definitions for `buffer_t`, `buffer_s`, and as others have suggested, show what you have tried.

Comment: Show the types and struct declarations or get closed.

Comment: Personally, I would call the appendBuffer() function. It seems to do just that.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
typedef char* buffer_s;
typedef buffer_s* buffer_t;

int appendBuffer(buffer_t buffer, char c)
{
    int size;
    char *outbuf;
    size = strlen(*buffer);
    outbuf = malloc(size+2);
    strcpy(outbuf,*buffer);
    *(outbuf+size) = c;
    *(outbuf+size+1) = 0;
    free(*buffer);
    *buffer = outbuf;
    return (size+1);
}
```